# terminal displays different username than login

Tags: macos, terminal

I am logged into my own computer as username geoff. When I open a terminal I have as prompt:

```
Geoffs-MacBook-Air:~ org1$
```

The org1 is my *work* username! I have no login of that username for this computer except for when I need a to access work from home, and I do this with VPN. At the moment the VPN is not connected.

What is my computer doing? What do I need to do to have a normal prompt?

Comment: Did you check this question? Just checking.
http://superuser.com/questions/451229/why-is-the-name-of-my-computer-wrong-in-terminal

Comment: No, I checked on SO. I will follow this up. Thx for the hint.

Comment: @theMarceloR I have had a look and it isn't the same. I have the correct hostname, but the wrong username. The problem is that when I use sudo I get (eventually) `org1 is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Comment: I read your question again and this is indeed weird, did you check `cat /etc/passwd`? did you try to `exit` and open another Terminal instance? If everything fails... I've found this cool comic here to cheer you up: http://xkcd.com/838/ :)

Comment: What should this `cat /etc/passwd` tell me? By the way, when I do a `whoami` I get org1. I tried simply `login geoff` plus passwrod, and it seems to work, but the `whoami` remains as org1. The comic is very apt at this time of year!

Comment: On Linux, /etc/passwd is the file that holds the OS logins, but looks like you will find the OSX users somewhere else: http://superuser.com/questions/191330/users-in-etc-passwd-on-mac-os-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a similar question in Ask Different. I followed the instructions laid out in the solutions there. It seems that "Your user name can be Geoff and the account's internal (unix) short name org1 and everything would be explained." The full information is at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76068/whoami-is-not-who-i-am